# arduino & drivers to control 5 brushed CIM motors independently?

Tags: arduino-mega, motor

i am a complete newbie in electronics but i'm a bit familiar with C.
i am building a machine that requires 5 little engines (12V 2.5in brushed CIM motors) & motor drivers (i need to adjust each motor's speed).
i've got an arduino UNO which i think is too small to control that many motors.
i would like to know if the setup i want was feasible to your opinion and which ardunio would i need to do that ?
i guess an Arduino Mega ?

also, i came accross this tutorial : https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-dc-motor-control-tutorial-l298n-pwm-h-bridge/
it explains how to configure an arduino with a driver & two motors.

in fact i want to prepare the same kind of thing but with 5 motors that i can control independently.

which hardware would you recommend to do such a thing please ?

many thanks !
regards

Comment: Yes, with an UNO and a few of those L298 modules you should be able to control 5 motors independently, no problems.  Try the tutorial you gave the URL for and you'll see how to use more than 1 motor driver.

Comment: thanks. However i see that these drivers can control 2 engines, so i would need three of them. can i connect all three on a UNO ? will i have enough ports etc. ?
also, isnt there a better solution (like having 1 driver that can control up to 5 engines ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have just enough I/O with UNO, so long as you don't want to connect any other hardware/sensors.  Since this is unlikely, it would be better to use another board like Mega, but I'll provide solutions anyway in case you want to try them out:

- **Option 1**:  For 5 motors controlled with L298N boards you'll need 15 output pins, 5 of which should be PWM.  Fortunately, there are 5 PWM outputs on the Arduino UNO on `PORTB` and `PORTD`.  The remaining 10 outputs need only be digital (`PORTB` has 1 and `PORTD` has 5).  You can use `DDRC` and `PORTC` commands to change function of the analog inputs labeled A0-A5, making them digital output, thereby gaining 6 more digital output pins for a total of 12 (more than the minimum 10 needed).
- **Option 2**:  It is possible to use other PWM motor drivers that reduce number of pins required.  Examples are DRV8838 ([link to supplier](https://www.pololu.com/product/2990)) and DRV8833 ([link to supplier](https://www.pololu.com/product/2130)) where 2 wires are needed per motor channel.  As a bonus, these drivers are also significantly more compact than L298N.